# T-SQL Can't test if table exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

DB: SQL Server 2008.

I have following query:

```
DECLARE @VAR FLOAT;

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM db.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sqlt_table_1'))
    BEGIN
        @VAR = (SELECT 1.0 FROM db.schema.sqlt_table_1);
    END;

SELECT @VAR;
```

If I have table sqlt_table_1, I execute query.
This query works if executed from SQL editor like DBeaver. However if this query is executed from a SCADA software utilizing Microsoft SQL JDBC Driver 4.0 compliant driver I get following error:

> caused by SQLServerException:Invalid object name 'db.schema.sqlt_table_1'

1. Why do I get this error?
2. How to make this SQL query work in the SCADA?

Comment: FYI SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for well over a year; you should really be looking at upgrade paths ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when the object `db.schema.sqlt_table_1` doesn't exist the statement fails. It doesn't matter if the statement won't run, the batch must still be valid.

The statement `@VAR = (SELECT 1.0 FROM db.schema.sqlt_table_1);` isn't even valid though. You would be better off with this:

```sql
USE db;
GO
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'sqlt_table_1' AND SCHEMA_NAME = N'schema') THEN 1 END;
```